# I need to find a value in file between >STRING<

Tags: bash, grep, string

I have a file: example here:

```
    <hello>TestFile</hello>
    <test>2018-04-30</test>
    <greetings>mycomputer</greetings>
    **<Iwanthis>6.1.0</Iwanthis>**
    <example>20180411</example>
    blah blah
```

I'm looking to grep the value (in this case 6.1.0) from between 
6.1.0

is there an way to grep the file to grab the XXXX value?

Comment: Is this an XML file?

Comment: Sorry - this a standard file - Not XML

Comment: I should mention - I need a solution in Bash - sorry for not mentioning it!

Comment: Bash is just a shell, not much of a text editor. You’re looking for a command-line solution? Grep, awk, sed, that sort of thing?

Comment: Yup - any of that would suffice once I can assign the XXXX into a variable to manipulate :P It's the special characters that are confusing me.

Answer (score 3):

Sure looks like an XML file. Add a root note and use an XML parser:

```
$ { echo '<r>'; cat file; echo '</r>'; } | xmlstarlet sel -t -v //Iwanthis
6.1.0
```

Answer (score 2):

If you can trust that there will be one opening tag and one closing tag on that line, you can use this as field separator for `awk`:

```
awk -F "</*Iwanthis>" '(NF > 1){print $2}' yourfile
```

This will fail on a lot of artificial cases. To be more strict, you could use `sed`:

```
sed -n 's_.*<Iwanthis>\(.*\)</Iwanthis>.*_\1_p' yourfile
```

The `-n` suppresses default output, so you just get output on the matching line. I did chose the underscore as delimiter for the `s` command to avoid escaping the slash. The `s` command will replace the whole line by the part between the opening and closing tag (the `\1` refers to the `\(.*\)` part)
Of course you can still create weird cases to make this fail.

Comment: I feel bad now - I tried for hours last night and did it 100% in just a few minutes...

Comment: I salute you SIR!!! Perfect - Does exactly what I wanted!!